# Hide a CSS class on Results pages

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to hide this class "mediad rh-flex-right-align" from my header only on page results. This class must appear on every other page except the Homepage where I already implement a javascript method to hide it.

Here the code to hide it from homepage:

```
<script>
        if (window.location.href == "https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/"){
document.getElementsByClassName("rh-flex-left-align")[0].style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

I'm searching the code to hide this CSS class also on https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/product-search/ and all pages which get this path (/product-search") (eg. https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/product-search/?s=test&post_type=product) :

```
<script>
        if (window.location.href == "https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/")
        if (window.location.href == "https://www.comparer-acheter.fr/product-search/") {
document.getElementsByClassName("rh-flex-left-align")[0].style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Obviously I'm not using the right code..
Glad to hear if you can help!

Flo

Comment: if you want to target a single element,why not just give it an id?  Grabbing them all and targetting the first one seems kind of guess-worky

Comment: @DMcCallum83 Using CSS ID could be a great option, but all pages have a common header (one PHP file)

Comment: ah, I see.  i get you now.  What's your thinking behind having both if statements in that second snippet?

Comment: @DMcCallum83 Hum, you're right a "or".. is probably more logic here. I'm terrible with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
if(location.href.split(location.host)[1].startsWith("/product-search")) {
    // set to display none
    document.getElementsByClassName("rh-flex-left-align")[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

you may need to use window.location.href...